# Is there a way to change something in Tool->Options via a macro?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'd like to be able to toggle easily between two values for "maximum number of parallel project builds" in Visual Studio 2008 (in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run). (When I'm planning on doing concurrent work I'd like to reduce it from 4 to 3.) I'm not too well versed in writing macros for the IDE. When I try recording a macro, and perform all the actions (open the dialog, change the setting, click OK), the only thing that gets recorded is this:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand ("Tools.Options")
```

Is my goal unattainable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be impossible, according to the MSDN page for *[Determining Names of Property Items in Tools Options Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165642.aspx)*

If it *was* possible, it would have been something like this:

```
Dim p = DTE.Properties("ProjectsAndSolutions","BuildAndRun")
p.Item("MaxNumParallelBuilds")
```

Comment: Shucks. Thanks for the reference though; that's pretty useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to now be possible in VS2010.  I'm no VB programmer, but here's what I got to work:

```
Sub EditConcurrentBuilds()
    Dim p As EnvDTE.Properties = DTE.Properties("Environment", "ProjectsAndSolution")
    Dim item As EnvDTE.Property = p.Item("ConcurrentBuilds")
    Dim text As String = InputBox("Enter number of concurrent builds", "Concurrent Build Option")
    Dim v As Integer = Val(text)

    If (v > 0 And v < 5) Then
        item.Value = text
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case, 4 is the most processors I've got on my machine.